# clearTimeout not works with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

setTimeout works, but clearTimeout is wrong. pn267 is a Navi-Div and uk267 is the first Level from Navi-Div. But in a extra Div.

```
 var myTimer;
 $('.pn267').hover(function() {
$('.uk267').animate({ opacity : 'show', height :  'show'}, 'fast');
 });
 $('.pn267').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).data('myTimer', setTimeout('$(".uk267").hide()', 500));
 });

 $('.uk267').hover(function() {
  myTimer = $(this).data('myTimer');
  clearTimeout('myTimer');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the quotes: `clearTimeout(myTimer);`

You are passing a string.  You need to pass the variable associated with the timeout itself.

Also I don't see a reason to use `$().data`.  Just use `myTimer = setTimeout(function(){$(".uk267").hide();}, 500);`.